# How to prevent overlapping borders of list elements in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

So I have a horizontal navigation bar I created by floating the list elements of an unordered list. It works fine but at the places where two list elements meet two borders form to create double the desired thickness. Is there a way to solve this?

**One Solution Attempted:**
I can specify the left and right border properties of individual list elements but this approach doesn't seem very scalable, but it works.

You can view my code and demo here http://jsfiddle.net/mscpg/
or inspect the code below

**css**

```
  #navigation_bar {
            overflow: hidden;
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 100%;
        }
            #navigation_bar li {
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
                width: 33%;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color: black;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation_bar">
    <li>Projection</li>
    <li>Real-Time</li>
    <li>Cleanup</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. For instance:

```css
#navigation_bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#navigation_bar li {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-left:none;
}
#navigation_bar li.first {    
  border-left:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation_bar">
  <li class="first">Projection</li>
  <li>Real-Time</li>
  <li>Cleanup</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mscpg/2/)

Also - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mscpg/1/) is with negative margin
​

Comment: Interesting approach.  So how does the browser know to apply the border on first li after you have declared no border on all li elements?

Comment: take a look at `#navigation_bar li.first` class. That is how it works. I just override border settings of `#navigation_bar li`

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be:

```
#navigation_bar li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

#navigation_bar li:first-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mscpg/3/

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the easiest route would be to add this to your "#navigation_bar li" definition, and if needed, just add a 1px margin-right to the ul to compensate:

```
margin-right: -1px;
```

If it were a table, you'd have the convenient option of the border-collapse property.

Comment: My last element border doesn't show (I have vertical so margin-bottom: -1px)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better idea to use `display: inline-block` instead of floating everything. For example:

```
 #navigation_bar {
        overflow: hidden;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #navigation_bar li {
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%; /* Slightly smaller width to fix the borders */
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
    }
```

Comment: Somehow it won't be formatted as code here, can anyone edit it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it, is to give the last item in the list an id or class, then give it its own border

see it in action [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ayoduw/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can always contain the list items in a div, then specify the borders for your list items to be half the desired viewed size. Then you can give the div they are enclosed in a left and right border that are half the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

What I personally do is use Scss and then only put a `bottom-border` on the last child. All other elements have a `top-border`

e.g.

```
&__your-row {
    border-top: 2px solid #D1D3D4;

    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #D1D3D4;
    }
  }
```

This will remove the overlapping borders.